# How to strip time and from from a non-datetime string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have strings that look something like this:

"Audio was recorded at 21:50:00 02/07/2019 (UTC) by device 243B1F05 at gain setting 2 while battery state was 3.6V."

I attempted to use the parser from dateutil:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
s = "Audio was recorded at 21:50:00 02/07/2019 (UTC) by device 243B1F05 at gain setting 2 while battery state was 3.6V."
dt = parse(s, fuzzy=True)
print(dt)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 1374, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 649, in parse
raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Audio was recorded at 21:50:00 02/07/2019 (UTC) by device 243B1F05 at gain setting 2 while battery state was 3.6V.
```

How can I extract the time and the date from this string? Is there a regex that'll allow me to do so in a single line?

Edit: Ideally, I'm looking for a solution I can easily apply to an entire column in a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Use re, for regex:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import re

s = "Audio was recorded at 21:50:00 02/07/2019 (UTC) by device 243B1F05 at gain setting 2 while battery state was 3.6V."

t = re.search(' (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) ', s).group(1)
dt = parse(t, fuzzy=True)
print(dt)
```

Output:

```
2019-02-07 21:50:00
```

Apply to a dataframe column:

```
pd.to_datetime(S.str.extract(' (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) ').squeeze(), format='%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how I would apply this across all values in a column in a pandas dataframe? I'm hoping to sanitize my data, but I'm not sure how I'd apply this to all the values in the column.

Comment: Sure, you don't need to import re... Try this  `pd.to_datetime(S.str.extract(' (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) ').squeeze(), format='%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y')`  where `S = pd.Series([s])` and S would be yoru dataframe column.

Comment: Thank you, Scott! An actual lifesaver :)